# How to get dynamic URL from ChildWindow using cypress

Tags: automation, cypress, window-handles, dynamic-url

I will click on button , it will then popup child window having dynamic URL each time.
Now i need to grab the dynamic URL and place it in cy.visit() and automate the things in child window

I tried in many ways, but couldn't solve the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These resources are great, [gleb blog](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-second-tab/) [filip blog](https://filiphric.com/opening-a-new-tab-in-cypress).

With no DOM details shown, you may be able to remove a `target` attr from the anchor and then `click()` to visit the link.

```js
cy.get('a')
  .invoke('removeAttr', 'target')
  .click()
```